# Google Analytics OAuth2 – PHP

Tags: google-analytics, analytics, oauth-2.0

wierd thing happening:

- i have 2 gmail account (A & B) with each has its own seperate google
  analytics account.
- I created an web application following http://www.daimto.com/google-oauth2-php/
- i login in with account A and i get all profiles under account A (which is correct)
- then i logout from account A.
- i login with account B and instewad of getting account B profiles, i still get account A profiles !!!

Moreover.. if i login with account B from another computer, i still get account A data!!!!!!! what am i doing wrong!

it's very wierd to login with account A and get another account data!!

any idea?

Comment: try destroying session completely and then do login with account B.

Comment: i tried that.. did not work